# How to get all column header checkbox selected in datagrid when I click on a checkbox which is not a part of datagrid in wpf?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, controls

I have a listbox in which I have added two controls i.e a checkbox and a datagrid side by side as a listboxitem. I have done it in a following manner:

**In Code behind:**
listBox1.items.Add(dt)

here dt is the table name.

**In Xaml:**

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" AlternationCount="2" MinHeight="305" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="537" >            
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
            <DataTemplate>                    
                    <StackPanel Name="stkPanel" MinHeight="80" MinWidth="500" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" 
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                                  MinHeight="75" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                  Name="dataGrid1" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                  MinWidth="470" 
                                  MaxWidth="900" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                  IsReadOnly="True" Background="#E6BAB7B7">
                            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox Name="colCheckBox" Content="{Binding}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        </DataGrid>
                        <CheckBox  Grid.Column="0" Height="35" Width="25" Name="IsDone" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="IsDone_Checked" />
                        </Grid>                        
                </StackPanel>                   
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now, when I check "IsDone" check box i.e a part of listboxitem ,all the checkboxes that are present in the column header of a datagrid(also a listbox item) should be checked for that particular listbox item row. If any of the checkbox in the column header of the datagrid is unchecked then "Isdone" check box should also be unchecked at the same time.Can you please suggest me how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `Element Binding`, this will solve the issue..

```
<DataTemplate>                    
                <StackPanel Name="stkPanel" MinHeight="80" MinWidth="500" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" 
                              AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                              MinHeight="75" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              Name="dataGrid1" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              MinWidth="470" 
                              MaxWidth="900" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                              IsReadOnly="True" Background="#E6BAB7B7">
                        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Name="colCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=IsDone, Mode=OneWay}" Content="{Binding}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <CheckBox  Grid.Column="0" Height="35" Width="25" x:Name="IsDone" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="IsDone_Checked" />
                    </Grid>                        
            </StackPanel>                   
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi Sankarann,
Thanks for your answer. But there is a slight problem. When I click on"IsDone" Checkbox ,all the checkbox present in the column header is checked.This works fine. But if any of the checkbox present in the datagrid column header is unchecked all the checkboxes are getting unchecked. What I need is just uncheck that particular column header checkbox that I want to uncheck along with the "IsDone "checkbox.

Comment: Set the `BindingMode=OneWay`.. this will not update the source and the others.. Check the updated answer..